# Make an object know what is happening inside a show function it's created

Tags: c++, qt

It's my first time using Qt IDE and I got stuck on a problem.
I have two classes that are connected through an interface. One is the ContrGeral and the other is the IAAutenticacao. The ContrGeral opens the main window. How can the class ContrGeral knows what's happening inside the show function that it has executed in order to make the class IAAutenticacao runs another window (or update it)?
I'm following the concept of interface, so I can't just put a sequential of actions inside the MainWindow class (created by ContrGeral). I need it to inform the ContrGeral somehow about the situation.
As the show function that opens the window don't return anything nor receive anything, I don't know what to do.

main.cpp

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "controladoras.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CntrGeral tela_inicial;
    tela_inicial.mostra();

    return a.exec();
}
```

controladores.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLADORAS_H
#define CONTROLADORAS_H

#include "interfaces.h"
#include "dominios.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class CntrGeral {
  private:
    IAAutenticacao *cntrIAAutenticacao;
    IAUsuario *cntrIAUsuario;
    IAEventos *cntrIAEventos;
    MainWindow inicial;

  public:
    void setIAAutenticacao(IAAutenticacao *);
    void setIAUsuario(IAUsuario *);
    void setIAEventos(IAEventos *);

    void mostra();

};

void inline CntrGeral::setIAAutenticacao(IAAutenticacao *cntrIAAutenticacao) {
    this->cntrIAAutenticacao = cntrIAAutenticacao;
}

void inline CntrGeral::setIAEventos(IAEventos *cntrIAEventos) {
    this->cntrIAEventos = cntrIAEventos;
}

void inline CntrGeral::setIAUsuario(IAUsuario *cntrIAUsuario) {
    this->cntrIAUsuario = cntrIAUsuario;
}

void inline CntrGeral::mostra() {
    inicial.show();
}

#endif // CONTROLADORAS_H
```

The problem is at inicial.show(), once it is executed it does not return anything.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you exactly want to know on what happening in `MainWindow`?

Comment: For exemple, if I press a button in mainwindow, how can  the ContrGeral class receive the input?

Comment: That's what [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more knowledge about `Qt signals and slots`. read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) before.

Then you can do the connections as follows:

- First add slots in your class `CntrGeral`:

***controladores.h***

```cpp
class CntrGeral {
...
public slots:
    void onMainWindowPressButton();
...
}
```

- Then connect and add the implementation of the slot:

***controladores.cpp***

```cpp
CntrGeral::CntrGeral()
{
    ...
    // connect for example "pushButton" (a QPushButton's object)
    // Which is a member of your MainWindow's object "inicial"
    connect(inicial.pushbutton, SIGNAL(release()), 
            this, onMainWindowPressButton());
    ...
}
CntrGeral::onMainWindowPressButton()
{
    /** TODO after push button pressed **/
}
```

Hope it helps you.